# R - Scraping with rvest package

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to get the data from the "Team Statistics" table on this webpage:

`https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/CGY/2010.html`

I don't have a lot of experience with web scraping, but have made a few attempts with the XML package and now with the rvest package:

```
library(rvest)

url <- html("https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/CGY/2010.html")

url %>%
        html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='team_stats']")
```

And end up with what appears to be a single node:

```
{xml_node}
<table class="sortable stats_table" id="team_stats" data-cols-to-freeze="1">
[1] <caption>Team Statistics Table</caption>
[2] <colgroup>\n<col>\n<col>\n<col>\n<col>\n<col>\n<col>\n<col>\ ...
[3] <thead><tr>\n<th aria-label="Team" data-stat="team_name" sco ...
[4] <tbody>\n<tr>\n<th scope="row" class="left " data-stat="team ...
```

How do I parse this to just get the header and information in the two row table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `html_table` at the end of the chain:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html("https://www.hockey-reference.com/teams/CGY/2010.html")

url %>%
  html_node(xpath = "//*[@id='team_stats']") %>% 
  html_table()
```

Alternatively:

```
library(rvest)

url %>%  
  html_table() %>% 
  .[[1]]
```

Both solutions return:

> ```
>             Team AvAge GP  W  L OL PTS  PTS%  GF  GA   SRS  SOS TG/G PP PPO   PP% PPA PPOA   PK% SH SHA    S  S%   SA   SV%   PDO
> 1 Calgary Flames  28.8 82 40 32 10  90 0.549 201 203 -0.03 0.04 5.05 43 268 16.04  54  305 82.30  7   1 2350 8.6 2367 0.916 100.1
> 2 League Average  27.9 82 41 31 10  92 0.561 233 233  0.00 0.00 5.68 56 304 18.23  56  304 81.77  6   6 2486 9.1 2479 0.911    NA
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Note: the first solution returns a dataframe to begin with, and the alternate solution returns only the first column of the table, because of the dot placeholder with index. Not that I'm complaining, though.

Comment: Hm, the alternate solution (`.[1]`) returns the first element in the list of tables for me. Not just the first column. Anyways, I have updated my answer to use `.[[1]]` since we don't need a list at this point, we're only interested in the first table and we would only want `.[` if we were to select multiple elements from the list.